# Density of irrationals in rationals. Proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Bruckner gives the following definition of a dense set:

A set $E$ of real numbers is said to be dense in a set $A$ if every
interval $(a, b)$ that contains a point of $A$ also contains a point of
E.

I'll appreciate if someone gives me feedback on the following proof about irrationals being dense in rationals.

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Take any interval $(a,b)$. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, certainly there is $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ in the interval $(a,b)$. Suppose there is not $y\in (a,b)$ for $y\in\mathbb{Q}^c$. Now,  $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-n,n)$. Because for all $y\in\mathbb{Q}^c$ it is false that $y\in(a,b)$, then it must be that $\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}$, but this is clearly false.

I took this exercise from Bruckner's Elementary Real Analysis

[image]

Comment: If you're going to assume the rationals are dense in the reals, then just show that the numbers $\sqrt2+r$ are all irrational for rational $r$ and are dense in the reals.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of the open intervals $(-n,n)$. That fact does not imply $\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}$. Your 
"proof" makes no sense to me. Even the phrase "irrationals are dense in the rationals" makes no sense. If you want to prove you can approximate any rational with irrationals, see @GerryMyerson 's comment.

Comment: But as you have set out the argument, it seems to me that it would still be possible for there to be one interval $(a,b)$ containing no irrational.

Comment: I think Bruckner made a mistake calling this property "dense *in* a set"; it's more "dense *near* a set".

Comment: Care to engage with us, Mango?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for your answer. I did see a proof of the argument you said at the beginning. However I think that in any interval, be it closed or open, or of the form [a,b) (for a<b), there must be an irrational number. I recall seen a proof of this fact by contradiction (the name of the theorem I don't recall, but it is a famous name). It used decimal expansions. Which interval are you thinking of other than singleton intervals?

Comment: On the other hand, I moved to other exercises since I didn't really get the point that Bruckner was trying to make with this exercise :/. I googled the term Greg mentioned by i found nothing

Comment: It is certainly true that any nonempty interval containing more than one number contains an irrational. In your argument, knowing $y$ is not in the specific interval $(a,b)$ doesn't imply that, for all $n$, it's not in $(-n,n)$. @Greg was (I think) not saying that "dense near a set" is the accepted term for the concept, just that if Bruckner was going to make up this concept, Bruckner could have found a better name for it.

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson. Now I understand